# Continuous but bounded explanatory variable modelling

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I'm attempting to run a multivariate regression and a few of my variables are continuous but also fall in a specific range (eg 1-5). Since some of the ranges are quite large I do not want to set up hundreds of dummies.

Is there some way of including these variables in a way that accounts for their bounded nature? Surely just including them as as linear or log-linear would give an incorrect interpretation as it would not account for range maximums/minimums?

Comment: Are the bounded variables independent or dependent variables?

Comment: The bounded variables are independent variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with bounded *independent* variables. Look at it this way: whenever you train a model on some data, your IVs will always be bounded, simply because you have a finite training set. Your model does not care whether the IV are "intrinsically" bounded, or whether they could in principle take on any value. (In addition, pretty much every IV is bounded in the sense that there are values that will never occur in nature.)

This is different from bounded *dependent* variables, where an unfortunate setting of IVs could yield a model prediction that is outside the intrinsic bounds.

Of course, if you extrapolate, you may run into problems. But this is mostly independent of whether the extrapolation makes intrinsic sense or not.